# Is Kyrgyzstan currently undergoing a revolution?

Tags: revolutions, kyrgyzstan

A friend of mine just sent me some pictures that supposedly depict protesters demolishing the president's office in Kyrgyzstan, and claim that there's a revolution going on. The only western media I can find on this is [this New York Times article](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/10/05/world/asia/kyrgyzstan-election-protests.html), which describes protesting but not a revolution. (Edit: Since posting, the protests have received broader coverage among western sources, but none describe the scenes of revolution that I have seen pictures of.)

What is the current status of Kyrgyzstan?

Comment: There seems to be a number of articles about the protests: [Kyrgyzstan election: Protesters storm parliament over vote-rigging claims](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-54422884) (BBC), [Kyrgyzstan election: 120 taken to hospital following result protest](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/oct/05/kyrgyzstan-election-120-taken-to-hospital-following-result-protest) (The Guardian), [Protesters erupt in Kyrgyzstan after parliamentary election](https://apnews.com/article/kyrgyzstan-bishkek-archive-elections-parliamentary-elections-07b08773f53f68e465c270f02ebe62d2) (AP)

Comment: I'm not sure what we can add to the news coverage. Can you give us a few more details of the "scenes of revolution" you have seen pictures of, and how they differ from what's described in the news? I'm assuming you mean there's a significant difference in scale, but it would be helpful to answerers to be explicit.

Comment: @yannis I saw claims that protesters had seized control of the presidential mansion and parliament chamber, and also had taken control of the state television channel.

Comment: @slondr Does this item on Wikipedia answer your question?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_Kyrgyzstan_protests

Comment: @DaveGremlin it does, yes; looks like a lot more information has cycled through to English-language sources in the time since I asked this question. If you'd like to post that link as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_Kyrgyzstan_protests):

The 2020 Kyrgyzstan protests began on 5 October 2020 in response to the 2020 parliamentary election that was perceived by protestors as unfair.  The election lead to Sooronbay Jeenbekov becoming president and the subsequent arrest and conviction of former president Almazbek Atambayev on corruption charges.  The results of the election were annulled on 6 October 2020.

On the tenth of October, former Member of Parliament Sadyr Japarov, who was freed from prison on October 5 by protesters, was elected as interim Prime Minister by Parliament.

President Sooronbay Jeenbekov announced that he would resign once the new cabinet was formed.

Kyrgyzstan had faced two revolutions during the early 21st century, including the Tulip Revolution in 2005 and the Kyrgyz Revolution of 2010.